# How can I handle 401 request status with a single generator function?

Tags: architecture, httpresponse, redux-saga, saga

I have a little problem, I am working on a project when I can make some saga calls to the API, I have about 50 in my project, but ow I have to log out the user if the request status is 401, I did not take that in consideration at first because I did not know, but I have to do now.

So I have calls like that in three saga function ( 3 files ):

first :

```
const { data } = yield call(client.getProducts, { type: 0 });
```

second :

```
const { data } = yield call(client.getClients);
```

third :

```
const { isCreatedCorrectly } = yield call(client.createProduct, { user });
```

So I was extracting the data directly from the response, But now I have to something like this :

first :

```
const response = yield call(client.getProducts, { type: 0 });
if(response.status === 401 ) {
  yield put(logout());
  yield cancel();
}
const data = response.data; // and continue
```

second :

```
const response = yield call(client.getClients);
if(response.status === 401 ) {
  yield put(logout());
  yield cancel();
}
const data = response.data; // and continue
```

third :

```
const response = yield call(client.createProduct, { user });
if(response.status === 401 ) {
  yield put(logout());
  yield cancel();
}
const isCreatedCorrectly = response.isCreatedCorrectly ; // and continue
```

So there is something that is always repeated, and I want to make things cleaner, because from what you see I have to make changes in more that 50 file like that.

Is there a clean way to do that ? a middleweare to be created.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

here is some functions to have a cleaner code (a saga helpers)

First thing you can create a function that prepare request options :

```
export const prepareOptions = (method, { data, params, successMessage, headers }) => {
    return {
        requestOptions: {
            method: method || 'GET',
            headers: headers || {
                'Content-Type': CONTENT_TYPE.JSON
            },
            data
        },
        params,
        successMessage
    }
}
```

create a centrelized method in order to do the call http , in my case here i use fetch but you can use axios or whatever :

```
export function requestWithAuth(url, options) {
  const optionsWithAuth = {
    ...options,
    headers: {
      ...options.headers,
    },
  };
  if (!url) {
    throw new Error('Url cannot be empty');
  }
  return fetch(url, optionsWithAuth).then(checkStatus)
.then(parseJSON).catch((error) => {
      if (error.response && (error.response.status === 401 || error.status === 401)) {
        loginDataStorageService.clearLoginData();
        redirectToLoginWithBrowserHistory();
      } else {
        throw error;
      }
    });
}
```

and after that you create a saga helper to centralize code that handle http calls fails and timeout , success action (you can automate the success action instead of writing success action for each request) :

```
 function* callApi(apiPath, options = {}, type) {
        const requestOptions = options.requestOptions || DEFAULT_OPTIONS
        const URL = apiPath
        try {
            const { response, timeout } = yield race({
                response: call(requestWithAuth, URL, requestOptions),
                timeout: delay(120000)
            })
            const { ...payload } = response
            if (timeout) {
            //will invoke a reject action 
                yield put({ type: `${type}_REJECTED`, payload: 'timeout' })
            }
            //will invoke a success action 
            yield put({ type: `${type}_FULFILLED`, payload})
    
            return { response: payload}
        } catch (err) {
         //handle error 
            if (err.response && err.response.data) {
                const payload = { data: err.response.data.description }
                yield put({ type: `${type}_REJECTED`, payload })
            } else {
                yield put({ type: `${type}_REJECTED`, payload: err })
            }
            return null
        }
    }
```

so your call will be like this :

```
function* requestData(action) {
    const { numeroCompte } = action
    const path = END_POINT
    const options = prepareOptions(httpMethods.GET, {})
    yield call(callApi, path, options, action.type)
}
```